# Boolean Algebra with Max terms

Tags: boolean-logic, boolean-algebra

I want to simplify the following expression:
F = (A+B+C)(A+B'+C)(A'+B+C)

I have simplified it accordingly.

F = (A+B+C)(A+B'+C)(A'+B+C)

F = (A+C)(A'+B+C)

F = AA' + AB + AC + A'C + BC + C

F = AB + C(A + A' + B + 1) = AB + C

However, the correct answer is (A+C)(B+C).
Where in my "current" proof am I going wrong? I have seen the solution, but I want to know why my current approach is wrong.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a programming question as defined in the [help] guidelines. It appears to be more suitable for [math.se] instead.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about boolean logic and [math.se] instead of programming or software development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing wrong - it's just two different ways of expressing the same thing.

If the goal is minimization I would argue that your solution is "better" since it only references each term once.

[Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?t=crmtb01&i=(a+or+c)+and+(b+or+c)) is your friend in cases like this.